# How can I implement a breadth first search in python given parents instead of children

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, breadth-first-search

Given the following picture how can I do a breadth first search but given parents instead of children?

[image]

I'm working in python so I'm using dictionaries. In a regular approach I'd have the following dictionary:

```
graph = {
  'A' : ['B','C'],
  'B' : ['D', 'E'],
  'C' : ['F'],
  'D' : [],
  'E' : ['F'],
  'F' : []
}
```

The dictionary for my problem would look like the following:

```
graph = {
  'A' : [],
  'B' : ['A'],
  'C' : ['A'],
  'D' : ['B'],
  'E' : ['B'],
  'F' : ['C','E']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pragmatic solution is to create the top-down dictionary structure from the reverse one:

```
graph2 = { key: [] for key in graph }
for child, parents in graph.items():
    for parent in parents:
        graph2[parent].append(child)
```

And then perform the usual traversal on that dictionary.

Comment: Yea... I just was hoping there was a better way. Thank you though!

Comment: There is no better way, as you will really need to find the children of a parent, and you don't want to search through your inverted dictionary every time you need to find the children of a node. So best is to go once through the dictionary and immediately take note of all children of every node.